# In kubernetes + konga + kong, what is the correct configuration of the connection between konga and kong?

Tags: kubernetes, kong, kong-ingress, konga

I'm new at Kubernetes and Kong. I have running Kubernetes by Docker Desktop and installed Kong and Konga.
Konga is running at `http://localhost:1337`.
When I tried to add some connection, I'm not sure what is the correct Kong Admin URL. It's not clear for me if it should be the IP for Kong Admin Ingresse or Kong Admin.
I tried everything but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you deploy the Kong and Konga containers in separate pods, but in the same Kubernetes namespace, right? Then I think the best option is to connect them via the DNS address of the Kubernetes service (see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/).